A geometry problem involving a tangent of circumcircle at a vertex of triangle
This is a problem in a geometry test, which I'm using to practice, however I can't solve it so I decided to post it here, to (at least) find a hint, or a solution (if possible).
Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle, inscribed circumcircle $(O)$, altitude $AD$, orthocenter $H$. Let $K$ be the reflection of $A$ through $(O)$. The tangent of $(O)$ at $A$ intersects the line $BC$ at $S$. Two lines $SK$ and $OD$ intersects at $Q$. $AD$ intersects $(O)$ at $P$. let $N$ be the intersection of two lines $PQ$ and $SC$. Prove that $NH\parallel SA$.
My attempts:

Let $E$ be the intersection of $OP$ and $BC$. It's well-known that $BC$ is the perpendicular bisector of $HP$ then $\triangle HEP$ is isosceles. Note that $OAP$ is also an isosceles triangle, then $HE \parallel AO$, therefore $HE\perp SA$. Thus $H$ is the orthocenter of $SAE$.

From that, we can deduce that: $\widehat{DPE}+\widehat{DEP} = 90^o = \widehat{HED}+\widehat{ESA}$. Since $\widehat{HED} = \widehat{DEP}$ then $\widehat{DPE} = \widehat{ASE}$. Then $SAEP$ is cyclic.


I found no way to proceed from the above. So please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.


(Similar in spirit to your previous problem that I wrote up a solution to) We want to show that $QP$ is tangential to $(O)$. Why does this give us the desired result?  $\quad$ This removes the need for $N$, though the point $Q$ is still weirdly defined (as it's not in relation to $P$), so a good next step would be to try to remove it.

Is there any way to solve this without proving $PQ$ is tangential to $(O)$ first Calvin? I'm trying to prove $NHEP$ is cyclic.

The answer to having alternative methods should be almost certainly yes (esp in Geometry where there are many ways to get to a result). $\quad$  EG Proving NHEP is cyclic is equivalent to QP is tangential to O, since $ND \times DE = DH \times DP = DP^2$. Ultimately what was important is $ \angle OPQ = 90^\circ$.

@CalvinLin : I have struggled with this problem for some days and can't figure out how to remove Q
. Could you please explain more or post an answer for this? Thanks

Proving that $PQ$ is tangent to $(O)$ is enough.
Here, I shall solve a subproblem and then use that to solve the original.

Subproblem :
Let $AB$ be a chord of $(O)$. $A'$ is $A$ reflected about $O$. $D$ is a point on $AB$. The perpendicular to $AB$ at $D$ meets the tangent to $(O)$ at $A$, at point $E$. $OD$, when extended, meets the tangent to $(O)$ at $B$, at point $C$.
Claim: $E$, $C$ and $A'$ are collinear.
Proof:
Let $CA'$ intersect $(O)$ at $F$. $M$ is the feet of the perpendicular from $B$ on $CD$. $O$, $M$, $F$ and $A'$ are concyclic since $CM \cdot CO= CB^2= CF \cdot CA'$. So, $\angle MFB= \angle MFA' + \angle A'FB= \angle AOD + \angle OAD= 180^{\circ}- \angle MDB$ and thus $DMFB$ is cyclic.
$\implies \angle DFB= 90^{\circ}$.
Now, $\angle DFA= \angle A'FB= \angle A'AB= \angle AED$ and hence $DAEF$ is cyclic.
$\implies \angle AFE= 90^{\circ}$ and so, $A'$, $C$ and $E$ are collinear (from collinearity of $A'$, $F$ and $E$).
In the actual Problem:
Let $Q'$ be the point where the tangent to $(O)$ intersects $OD$(extended). From earlier, points $S$, $Q'$ and $K$ are collinear and so, $Q'=Q$. Therefore, $PQ$ is tangent to $(O)$.

Thank you for your answer, it really helped me understand this problem.

@anonimo You're welcome :).
